# Mosquitto broker listening on two ports

Tags: c#, mqtt, mosquitto

On my PC is running mosquitto 1.6.3. Default port is 1883 but I set up also to run on 9001 and user websocket. The both ports are opened.

The question if I if create publisher app, does cthis publisher broadcast message on both ports? The thing is that I want to have desktop app and web app. Web app (subscriber) will use websocket.

This is my publisher:

```
private static void createPublisher()
{   
     MqttClient client = new MqttClient(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"));
     client.Connect(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
     string[] topic = { "sensor/temp", "sensor/humidity" };

     byte[] qosLevels = { MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_EXACTLY_ONCE, MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_EXACTLY_ONCE };
     String temp = "14";

     client.Publish("sensor/temp", Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(temp));

     client.MqttMsgPublishReceived += client_MqttMsgPublishReceived;
     client.MqttMsgSubscribed += client_MqttMsgSubscribed;
     client.MqttMsgUnsubscribed += client_MqttMsgUnsubscribed;
     client.MqttMsgPublished += client_MqttMsgPublished;

    }
```

I'm using M2MMQT.Net library.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, all listeners share the same topic space in mosquitto

This means a client connected to the native MQTT listener on port 1883 can be subscribed to by a client connected via MQTT over Websockets on port 9001 and vice versa.